# Problems with Game Of Life in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, conways-game-of-life

I'm working on Conway's Game of Life in python 2.7, and I'm getting an error I don't understand. In my algorithm to get the number of neighboring tiles that are True, I'm getting an index error.

```
if column < thesize:
    if board[row][column+1] == True:
        adjacents += 1
return adjacents
```

thesize is a variable used for generating the 2D grid, so that first line should prevent the error... But it doesn't. The full code is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B07YADKKdCjWbTEyYzFQZW4tazQ&authuser=0), can anyone point out my mistake? If the link doesn't work, please let me know.

Comment: I suspect you're trying to access an index of `board` that doesn't exist.

Comment: I know that, but I didn't see why that was the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sequence with a length of `n` has a maximum element index of `n - 1`. Nonetheless you're trying to access element `n - 1 + 1`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Just looked at your code, and this is indeed your problem. You can fix this by replacing `thesize` with `thesize - 1`.